# Checking if field is null

Tags: java, if-statement, exception, null

Below is my code, I'm trying to check if xCoord is null, or empty, so I can throw an exception. How do I do so?
I tried with try/catch if xCoord == null but that won't work.

```
String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("X Coordinate", "Enter an x coordinate");
int xCoord = Integer.parseInt(x);
String y = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Y Coordinate", "Enter a y coordinate");
int yCoord = Integer.parseInt(y);
String width = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Radius", "Enter the length of the radius");
int radius = Integer.parseInt(width);
```

Comment: Only `Objects` can be null

Comment: `int` can never be null, use `Integer` instead or check for `x == null` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xCoord` is an `int` which is a primitive type. Primitives cannot be `null`s. They are reserved for reference types.

What you can do is to check if `x` is a null. Can it be? Yes, it can. It'll be `null` if user doesn't click `OK` (Cancel, esc, X).

So the proper way to check it is:

```
String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("X Coordinate", "Enter an x coordinate");
if (x == null || x.isEmpty()) {
    //throw Exception or set x to "0" - I'll set to 0
    x = "0";
}
int xCoord = Integer.parseInt(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have `xCoord` it's already to late. You need to check `x` before you attempt to parse it:

```
String x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("X Coordinate", "Enter an x coordinate");
if (x == null || x.length() == 0) {
    // Throw a meaningful exception
}
int xCoord = Integer.parseInt(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

`xCord` is an `int`, which is a *native type*, which cannot be null. Never.

Only object references can be null (for example, if `xCord` was defined as `Integer xCord`).